# Can User's View Their ODIC Claims?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

From my understanding the OIDC claims are sent via JWTs.  Does this mean the client user can view their own claims in the JWT?

I'm considering adding a claim value that I would be ok with the client app having access to, but not the user using the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JWT is a **public** token and can be *captured and read* by the user. Which is just fine. The important thing is that the claims can't be altered.

If you have sensitive data (that is not part of security) then don't put it in the token but use a session or read it from the store (e.g. database).

In case of IdentityServer you can use [reference tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html), the alternative for JWT. Then only a key is used while the information is kept hidden for the user.